# Trying to "break" the Collatz Conjecture and generate 3n-1 sequences (there will be cycles)

Tags: python, math

This is what I have done so far:

```
def collatz_sequence(x):
        seq = [x]
        if x < 1:
           return []
        y = x*2
        while x != 1 and x != y:
           if x % 2 == 0:
                x = x / 2
           else:
                x = 3 * x - 1
           seq.append(x)    # Added line
        return seq

x = 5
while x < 10:
        print collatz_sequence(x)
        x += 1
```

So it stops in two out of three cases: It actually works and goes to 1, it does not work and goes back to itself (5 -> 14 -> 7 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5). It does not stop if it basically enters into another cycle, such as (9 -> 26 -> 13 -> 35 -> 104 -> 52 -> 26).

How do I go through the sequence at the end of each loop and have it stop if it repeats an integer already in the sequence? (I imagine I can get rid of the x != y part of the while statement doing this).

Comment: The Collatz Conjecture uses `3n+1`, not `3n-1`.

Comment: I know. I wanted to do it with 3n-1 instead to see what the cycles look like. Hence why I say "breaking" it. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare may be useful. Or you can use a set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if x in seq:` operations.

```
def collatz_sequence(x):
        seq = [x]
        if x < 1:
           return []
        y = x*2
        while x != 1 and x != y:
           if x % 2 == 0:
                x = x / 2
           else:
                x = 3 * x - 1
           if x in seq:
                seq.append(x) # Add at end of list so you can see the loop in output
                break
           seq.append(x)    # Added line
        return seq

x = 5
while x < 20:
        print collatz_sequence(x)
        x += 1
```

A little care is needed in precisely when you test if x is in the sequence as you need to ensure the test is before the item is added.
I'm not sure what function the `y` variable serves.